# AlertView:Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I'm trying to do an alert view that gives the user a choice of 3 options to choose from. buttonIndex 1 and 2 are fine but when i select buttonIndex 3 thing happens. I want it in a way that when buttonIndex 3 is selected and alert view with 3 options should appear and it should call a different method depending on what buttonIndex the user selects. ***How do i fix this code(buttonIndex==3)????***

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        AddReferenceViewController *project =
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddRef"];
        project.projectdb = self.projectdb;
        [self presentViewController:project animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 2)
    {

        StyleViewController *style = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StyleController"];
        [self presentViewController:style animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 3)
    {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Styles"
                                                           message:nil
                                                          delegate: self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Harvard",@"Chicago", @"Vancouver",nil];
            if(buttonIndex == 1){
                [self Harvard];
            }
            else if(buttonIndex == 2){
                [self Chicago];
            }
            else if(buttonIndex == 1){
                [self Vancouver];
            }
            else{
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Information"
                                                           message:@"No Reference  added to this project"
                                                          delegate: self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Add Reference",@"Ref Style", @"Email References",nil];

            [alert show];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Button index should be 0, 1, 2 for the 3 buttons and not 1, 2, 3. This will remove the bug for you

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex):

> buttonIndex
>   The index of the button that was clicked. The button indices start at 0. If this is the cancel button index, the alert view is canceling. If -1, the cancel button index is not set.

Comment: I changed it to 0,1,2 but it doesn't call the functions... buttonIndex 0 and 2 do nothing and buttonIndex 1 does a segue(thats not whats in the function).

Comment: @yasmin - when you enter the method, print off the `buttonIndex ` to see what value you are getting. Also note, that [as mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28711177/377384), this way of doing things is deprecated in iOS8.

Answer (score -1):

Use a different delegate for each of your alert views.
Also, note this class is deprecated and you should use UIAlertController instead.

Comment: You do not need different delegates for each alert view. And suggesting the use of `UIAlertController` doesn't offer an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes, but using a different controller will make things clearer. The note about deprecation is an aside.

Comment: how do i use a UIAlertController please?

Comment: Hey Yasmin, the official docs show an example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/